# Getting some weird issue trying to run Cassandra on Windows 10

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to install Cassandra.  I followed the instructions here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEXtVn3zAqc

I had Java 14 and I when I tried to run Cassandra I got a message saying that Java 8 or 11 needs to be installed.  So, I got Java 11 from the link below.

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html

I downloaded Cassandra and added the path to Environment Variables.  I added the Java path to Environment Variables too.  Now, I navigate to the Cassandra path in the Command Prompt and type `'cassandra.bat -f'` and I get this message: `'Cassandra 4.0 requires either Java 8 (update 151 or newer) or Java 11 (or newer). Java 11.0.8 is not supported.'`  I already have Java 11; I got it just for Cassandra.  I am on Windows 10.  How can I make this work?

Comment: I just downloaded Java 8, installed it, and added that to the Environment Variables, and now I'm getting the same message.  This thing is looking for Java 8 and Java 11, both of which are installed, and apparently Cassandra still can't find them.

Comment: I just figured it out.  This link helped.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1waKtjNt88

Apparently there are two 'Environment Variables'; one is called 'Environment Variables For Your Account' and the other one is called 'System Environment Variables'.  You have to make the changes to the  'System Environment Variables', and then it works.

Comment: You should copy your second comment into an answer. Cheers!